# importing images in Vue component template

Tags: vue.js, webpack

i created a vue project using `vue-cli 3` and while working in my local env i managed to present all images in components html part the following way:

```
<template>
   <img class="logo" src="@/assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
</template>
```

in my machine the full path to the image (starting from the `src` folder as root) is `src/assests/images/logo.svg`
when running the project on the local env the image loads and it's source is 
`/assets/images/logo.svg` which redirects to `http://localhost:8080//assets/images/logo.svg`.
now when i upload the project  to my staging env the source changes (and i cant figure out why) to `src="/img/logo.230e726c.svg"` and the image is missing. 
following info i found online i also tried:

`src="~@/assets/images/logo.svg"` which didn't work as well .
any idea what am i missing here and how should i import images in my template? or how did the source url turn to this (what seems to be quite random) path?

**UPDATE**

i noticed that on my local machine , when inspecting the result in the dev tools, the content type is `Content-Type: image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8` and when inspecting on staging the content type is `content-type: text/html`
 plus there also another header which only appears in staging and its `content-encoding: gzip`
 , i'm not sure but does this should serve as some clue??

another thing worth mentioning, when trying to upload png every thing works fine and the image elemnt looks like this:

```
<img data-v-7d622f5c="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: Have you checked your assetsPublicPath variable in config env file?

Comment: haven't defined nor have one available

Comment: try static//img/logo.230e726c.svg

Comment: Re your update: webpack converts small images into inline data:image, that's what you're seeing there.

Comment: And the changed content type on the svg is because webpack is compressing the file for you; check your server config to make sure it's able to serve gzipped files.